# Custom TYPO3 back-end module CSRF token not applied

Tags: typo3

I have a custom backend module.

If an editor now has several browser windows showing this backend module, the following error message is always displayed:

```
#1417988921: The CSRF protection is necessary or invalid (More information)

TYPO3\CMS\Core\Exception thrown in file
vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/BackendModuleRequestHandler.php in line 82.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please provide the generated URL that is used to invoke the backend module (you can obfuscate specific extension names of course).

Answer (score 0):

...just a shooting from the hip: 
Check php.ini and increase the values for max_input_vars und upload_max_filesize. Helped me out of a similar trouble.

(I assume you have checked https://forge.typo3.org/issues/66704 before)

Comment: Ok and what sizes did you adjust?

Comment: Good remark. The TYPO3 Install Tool shows possible misconfigurations and suggestions concerning the PHP environment as well.